# Problemas ao usar nested_attributes e devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estou criando um formulário de configurações do usuário que usa o devise, estou usando nested attributes, mas por algum motivo o registro de configurações não é atualizado, mas sim deletado, alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo?

Formulário: 
https://pastebin.com/LphpYGCj
Log do console:
https://pastebin.com/VLNjSA6u

(Também tem esse id que é passado no formulário via um hidden_input que eu gostaria de remover)

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Sim, eu estava sendo muito burro e esqueci da importância do id, foi só deixar o mesmo como atributo permitido que começou a ocorrer o update e não o destroy. Mas o id fica salvo com "hidden_field", o que é uma tremenda falha de segurança deixar isso assim, então eu criei uma lógica no controller para pegar o id da setting do usuário sem receber via formulário, e desabilitei o id via hidden_input utilizando "include_id: false" no "fields_for".